# Minimisation in two unknowns and absolute value

Tags: optimization

> $$Error = \vert(\tan(\theta)*20 – (9.8/2V^2(\cos\theta)^2)*20^2  - 2.2)\vert$$

$\vert\bullet\vert $ indicate absolute value.

Is it possible to manually minimise the above equation and if so how do I go about it? Here both $\theta$ and $V$ are the independent variables and $Error$ is the dependent variable. I need to minimise the error.

Comment: As I see it, the formula you wrote reads  $$ Error=\left\vert 20\tan(\theta)-20^2\cdot\frac{9.8}{2}V^2\cos^2(\theta)-2.2\right\vert$$ Is it what you had in mind?

Comment: Or are the  $V$ and  $\cos \theta$ part of a denominator?

Comment: Sorry for my poorly written statement, but yes the V and cos theta are part of the denominator